# Filemaker Pro 14 Advanced -- Layout/Reports -- Like an Excel Pivot Table?

Tags: pivot-table, filemaker

I am using Filemaker Pro 14 Advanced (Mac) and I'm having problems with the setup of Layouts/Reports.

I need a report that looks Like a typical Excel Pivot Table.

I want to show MULTIPLE (not just one or two) columns (months) with MULTIPLE rows (products). I would also prefer to have sub-totals by YEARS (in the columns) and sub-totals by PRODUCT-CATEGORY (in the rows) as well.  AND would prefer these to both be "collapsible".  All fairly typical in an Excel PT.

I can't see how you get the MONTHS into the columns in an FM Layout?

I've tried the FM TABLE VIEW but it's not even close to this (using group by and grand totals).

FM's LIST VIEW shows loads of rows (using sub-summaries etc.) but I don't want to scroll hundreds of products per month for EVERY month.  And how to compare #s side-by-side?

If this can't be done simply in FM is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, FileMaker does not offer any native functionality for pivot tables/crosstab reports. You will have to construct it more or less manually. There are several techniques out there, you can check out this one which is fairly simple.
https://www.teamdf.com/blogs/a-lightweight-cross-tabular-data-entry-method/
Other approaches may use more convoluted relationships, or use the web viewer to display a generated html rendering. It may work, depending on your printing needs. Web Viewers print poorly in general.
You may also want to check out this virtual list approach: https://filemakerhacks.com/2016/04/27/virtual-list-reporting-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for those ideas - the weblinks are very interesting.  I will pursue them but will start by just re-uploading my FM database to Excel and using Pivot Table's there.